# Htaccess multiple redirect for one page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a question:
I've made a blank page for my future website, and I have a problem.

There is one page which is served by these urls (account.php):

http://site.domain/en/account/  -- able to access but if there is no / , I'm unable to access it
http://site.domain/en/account/create/  -- able to access, but I have the same problem
http://site.domain/en/account/create/verify/ -- not able to access with current htaccess

My htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^([a-z]{2})- [NC]
## Rewrite Rules
RewriteRule ^account/?$ /%1/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(account)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /$2.php?language=$1&type=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
```

So what im trying to do, is to make all of the redirects accessible through htaccess.

For example, with data in htaccess mentioned above, im able to access account page and create page, but not verify page. if i change it to:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(account)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /$2.php?language=$1&type=$3&subtype=$4
```

I'm able to access create and verify pages, but not the account page itself.

So what i'm trying to achieve, is to be able to access all of these 3 pages with one htaccess rule, so basically with just redirecting user with htaccess and without help of php, even though account.php determines which request was made and serves the correct page for the request

Are there any good books to read about htaccess and related issues, because I have no idea of what it is and how to work with it

Comment: I think you can check AskApache http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess.html for the htaccess. As for the rest of the issues you list, I am not sure I've understood them... Could you edit the question to explain a little better? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^([a-z]{2})- [NC]
## Rewrite Rules
RewriteRule ^account/?$ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(account)(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?)?/?$ /$2.php?language=$1&type=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Now im able to access account and verify, but not create, returns 404 error